# 4th gear to 5th gear puts to 3rd gear often?

Tags: transmission, clutch, manual-transmission, car

[image]

R, 1, 2, 3, 4 works great. But when i am in highway driving 90km to 120km and trying to switch to 5th gear. I have a strange problems.

When Engine is running live:
- from 4th dragging straight to 5th brings me to 3rd

When Engine is not running car is stopped moving 4th to 5th gear never fails.

Pilot check: always made sure the clutch was 100% pushed while moving / changing gears.

What might be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack :o) What kind of car are we talking about here? Year/make/model/engine? I would bet you've got some slop in the linkage which may be causing it not to move all the way while shifting, which would put you in the wrong gear. If so, has a lot less to do with technique and more to do with worn mechanical bits/pieces.

Comment: Yeah, check your shifter bushings first. I once had a Ford Escort with the bushings in such bad condition that you could put the gear into 5th and then there was so much play it could look like it was in 1st.

Comment: @Paulster2: Mitsubitshi carsima/1998. When the car is not driving then i can move smoothly. But when i am driving in 4th gear and trying to move 5th gear i feel i am almost to the 5th but it actually went to 3rd.

Comment: I do not want to drive in 5th gear. My Question to you guys. Can you drive 115km in 4th gear too?

Comment: *"Can you drive 115km in 4th gear too?"* That's [I have 5th gear issue , can i drive in 4th gear at 100km to 115km?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/46952/7356), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A driving technique question - you need to make sure that you move across as well as up when changing from 4th to 5th. This was a common error causing exopensive damage on some cars when 5th gear was "new"...

Comment: When its in 4th gear, i hold the gear and push up push to the right top. But often i end up in 3rd gear in the middle of highway where everybody is driving 120km

Comment: I knew lots of cars that had blown engines for exactly that error...

Answer (score 1):

My Mustang is loaded towards the 3-4 shift. The shifter must be positively moved left for a 1-2 shift and to the right for the shift into 5th.

A little practice may solve the problem.

Comment: My jag is loaded exactly the same but the loading is gentle and if you are a bit "rough" or heavy handed you lose the feeling...

Answer (score 0):

As Paulster2 and finleyarcher mentioned in the other comments, there are some mechanical issues that can cause that.

However, as Solar Mike noted, technique can also cause this.

The distinguishing questions are "is the car new" and "have you always had this issue shifting 4th to 5th with this vehicle or is this a new problem?"

I've driven some manual cars that were very picky about the shifter being operated with ***very*** distinct, *separate*, actions, and I've driven some that didn't care too much. If this is a new issue, then it's probably from mechanical wear. If you're the original owner and you've had problem since the beginning, then it's most likely a technique problem.